# JAVA <identifier> expected

Tags: java

Could someone help me? I am new to program with java, am I stuck in a bug for a long time

Here is the Error message:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - identifier expected

```
at pkg18148600a_assignment1.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:12)
```

Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1

Here is my code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Member member[] = new Member[6];
    int sequence[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            member[i] = new Member(args[i], Integer.valueOf(args[i+1]));
        }
    }

    int k = 0;
    boolean swap;
    do{
        swap = false;
        if (member[k % 7].compareTo(member[(k+1) % 7]) > 0){
            temp = sequence[k % 7];
            sequence[k % 7] = sequence[(k+1) % 7];
            sequence[(k+1) % 7] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
        k++;
    } while(swap);

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    System.out.printf("%s, %d\n", member[i].getName(), member[i].getAge());

}

public static class Member implements Comparable<Member> {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Member(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Member(){
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Member a) {
        if (age == a.age){
            return 0;
    }else if (age > a.age){
        return 1;
    }else return -1;


    }

}
```

Comment: what are the args that you are passing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

u get NullPointerException in the following line

```
member[k % 7].compareTo(member[(k+1) % 7]
```

because u just new even index here

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        member[i] = new Member(args[i], Integer.valueOf(args[i+1]));
    }
}
```

u have to remove if statment or other thing related to ur logic

and other thing Integer.valueOf(args[i+1]) cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. arrays start from 0 index

Comment: thx a lot, i got stuck into my own logic and forgotten there are only even indices